# how to find the time complexity of this algorithm?

Tags: c++, recursion, time-complexity, master-theorem

```
int multiply(int a[],int low,int high,int modulus)
{
    if(low==high)
        return (a[low]);
    else
    {
       int mid = (low+high)/2;
       int x = multiply(a, low, mid, modulus) % modulus;
       int y = multiply(a, mid+1, high, modulus) % modulus;
       return ((x*y) % modulus);
    }
}
```

Is its time complexity O(log n) or it is O(n) ?

Please help me.

Comment: What do *you* think the complexity is?

Comment: Do you know about the [Master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem)? Try to apply it to your algorithm.

Comment: Try it on different values of n, and plot a graph. Then look at the shape

Comment: Divide and Conquer strategy for this is clearly define in : http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/algorithms/chap2.pdf, see section 2.1. Just googled "algorithm complexity recursion divide and conquer"

Answer (score 1):

You are making `O(N)` calls to `multiply`, where `N == high - low` at the top-level call.

E.g. take `N=2^K` for convenience. You are recursing `K` levels deep before you hit the case where `low==high`. At each level, you have `2^(K-1)` calls. They add up to a total of `N - 1` calls (1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 64 = 127).

For general `N` the scaling behavior is the same, which you can prove using Case 1 of the [Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) based on the recursion relation `T(N) = 2 T (N / 2)` of your function.